# Why is my UART communication between X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 (BlueNRG-M2SP) and Nucleo-G070RB not working?

Tags: stm32, uart, hci, bluenrg

I am currently having trouble making a simple UART communication (+ the HCI command-based protocol) between the X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 shield embedding a BlueNRG-M2 (which itself embeds a BlueNRG-2) and my Nucleo-G070RB. I cannot use SPI for this.

I also created a [ST topic](https://community.st.com/t5/interface-and-connectivity-ics/uart-communication-between-x-nucleo-bnrg2a1-bluenrg-m2sp-and/m-p/608054#M10494)

First, on X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 side (BlueNRG-2) :

- I downloaded the FW package [STSW-BNRG2N-V320](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-bnrg2n-v320.html)
- I used the documentation UM2666 "Getting started with the X-CUBE-BLE2 Bluetooth Low Energy software expansion for STM32Cube" as support,
- I flashed the X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1, i-e the embedded BlueNRG-2, using the BlueNRG-1_2 Flasher Utility (STSW-BNRGFLASHER), with the STSW-BNRG2N-V320 in order to emulate it with a BlueNRG-2N
  -I removed all Resistors / Jumpers from the SPI and unnecessary lines : (SPI_MOSI R80 & SPI_MISO R79 ), (SPI_CSN R77), (SPI_IRQ / BOOT R85 & R82) , (SPI_CS R70, R76 & R86), (GPIO R81 & R84), (Jumpers J11, J12, J13, J14, J15 (I have a doubt about J15, but I think this is just required while flashing) )
- I added all required 0 Ohm Resistors + Jumpers : R83 for DIO12 (SEL pin on BlueNRG-2N) & Jumper J10 (3v3 <-> VDD).
- I also added 0 Ohm Resistors R71 and R73 as I firstly thought these 2 lines (DIO4 & 5) were the UART lines. But if I understood correctly, these are just for application serial com when used and the emulation of BlueNRG-2N uses the DIO8 & DIO11 as UART Pins.

Then, on NUCLEO-G070RB side (STM32G0xx) :

- I have an already working project running correctly on this board
- I took the following project example: STM32L - BLE_Beacon_NWK from BlueNRG-1_2 DK 3.2.3 and extracted all I needed , using the documentation "STM32L - BlueNRG-1,2 network coprocessor (UART mode)" from the doxygen doc as support.
- I made an UART Rx/Tx module working, using the HCI commands defined in the imported libraries. This module is correctly working in:

  - TX because I validated it using a USB to Serial converter on my laptop with a python script using a hci lib : the data is correctly sent.
  - RX because if I make the loop TX <-> RX on the same UART, I receive exactly what was sent. I haven't tested the reception of HCI Events data, but that is not the pb here.

Finally, I mapped / configured / checked the GPIOs / buses like this:

- BlueNRG-M2SP Pins 1 & 2 untouched
- BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 3 = DIO4 = ? < --- > STM32G0xx PA9 = unused & floating
- BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 4 = DIO5 = ? < --- > STM32G0xx PA10 = unused & floating
- **BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 5 = VDD is correclty at 3V3**
- BlueNRG-M2SP Pins 6 & 7 untouched
- BlueNRG-M2SP Pins 8 correctly grounded
- BlueNRG-M2SP Pins 9 untouched
- ****EDIT** " BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 11 = DIO11 = UART_RXD (BNRG-2N) " < --- > STM32G0xx PB2 = USART3_TX.**

  - When unconnected and BlueNRG-M2SP in correct state, pin is correclty floating
  - When connected + a USB Serial converted RX wire connected, HCI data is good (interpreted by py python)
- ****EDIT** " BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 10 = DIO8 = UART_TXD (BNRG-2N) " < --- > STM32G0xx PB0 = USART3_RX**

  - When unconnected and BlueNRG-M2SP in correct state, pin is correclty at 3V3, and drops to floating when BlueNRG-M2SP is in reset
  - When connected to RX wire of a USB Serial converter or a Scope NOTHING, stays at 3v3
- BlueNRG-M2SP Pins 12 to 18 untouched
- **BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 19 = RESETN < --- > STM32G0xx PA8 = GPO set to 1 when want to enable the BRNG. Correctly set to 1 during communication**
- **BlueNRG-M2SP Pin 19 = DIO12 = SEL (BNRG-2N) < --- > STM32G0xx PB4 = GPO set to 1 when want to enable the UART. Correctly set to 1 during communication**

As a result, BlueNRG-M2SP should be working as BlueNRG-2N: is powered up & grounded correclty, is enabled (resetn = 1) & SEL pin = 1 for UART, has UART TX & RX mapped & receives good HCI commands, but no response and my application commands end all in timeout.

I tried swapping RX & TX just in case, nothing either.

Have I missed something ? Like the DIO 4 & 5 are maybe the ones to use ? The "emulation" FW is not UART HCI protocol compatible ?

I really appreciate any response, I am a bit in a pickle here ... ‌‌

Max.Pach

Comment: Have you verified that the microcontroller UART works correctly for both sending and receiving arbitrary data? Can you scope/use logic analyzer to see if your software fails to see the data, or no data is actually physically sent over the line? Additionally, try to use the slave device with PC's UART (via USB/UART bridge), you can use something like Yat (on Windows) to send and receive raw binary data. Basically, test every component of software and hardware individually first, see what you can learn from it.

Comment: Hi Ilya

I did all of the scoping / verification on the MCU TX line, and on MCU RX line (BlueNRG TX) nothing at all. The only thing that happen is the level going up when I reset the BlueNRG, then going back to 0V, stable.

My app & my µcontroller are not the issue here, as I tested to loop TX & RX on it: I receive all the sent bytes in the low level UART RX functions. Then, what does the App with it afterwards will be another problem, I need first to establish this comm with the BlueNRG.

Comment: I also sent using minicom and a USB to UART bridge the exact same HCI frame that is first sent in my App : [ 0x01 0x0f 0xfc 0x02 0x01 0x07 ], using the func aci_hal_set_tx_power_level(). Ofc the BlueNRG was in a live state (RESTN to 1 and DIO12 to 1). No response after a few attempts, nothing on the BlueNRG TX line.

So far, I am 99% sure that I do something wrong with the BlueNRG itself: either the FW inside isn't working as I intend or I missed a step.

Comment: I also used a steval-idb008v2 Eval Board. I isolated the BlueNRG-2 on it from the Main MCU & sensors & level shifter & SPI switch. I Flashed it with different FW, including the  STSW-BNRG2N-V320 and the DTM UART, same result. However I noticed something weird: the TX pin of the BlueNRG-2 is low and the RX is high when unconnected.

Answer (score 0):

*Copied reply from ST community:*

Nevermind, seems to come from the way you flash the BlueNRG board ...

I was using the X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 & the STEVAL-IDB008V2. Using the latter, I of course made the HW workarounds to enable external com without having the embedded components in the way.

Using RF Flasher and a bunch of different Example apps (DTM Uart, Beacon, the BlueNRG 2N "emulation"), no response, on both boards.

- SWD only for X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1
- SWD & UART with STEVAL-IDB008V2 (as there is a USB to serial converter STM32 on the board that manages that flashing function). No response with GUI either.

Using the BlueNRG DK graphical app, I managed to flash through UART the STEVAL-IDB008V2 with a DTM Uart image that now communicates with Both GUI & my FW on external Nucleo-G070RB. Howerver, when I compare the flash with the DTM Uart image using RF Flasher, there are differences.

I am really confused with that. This should not happen. Flashing the device with an example bin from the BlueNRG DK folders through RF Flasher should work. Now I am stuck with the X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 not working as there is no way to program it using the BlueNRG DK graphical app.

So what I am missing there ? I will try on Ubuntu using OpenOCD but I fear the same result will happen.